# Vertex Groups are not being created

Tags: rigging, vertex-groups

I'm a Blender Newbie - I'm trying to follow an online tutorial that rigs wheels to bones on a car.

In the example, the presenter is going into "Pose Mode" and re-naming the bones.  In his example, this is automatically creating Vertex Groups.  He then selects the wheel and assigns it to the Vertex Group.

I am not seeing the Vertex Groups being created; I tried manually creating the Vertex Groups, but I don't see the 'Assign' button to associate the wheel object with the Vertex Group.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thank you so much.

-Dan

Comment: When you parent you need to select the object, shift select the armature, CTRL P > With Empty Groups, it will create the vertex groups but won't assign any vertex to these groups for the moment. Now you can select the vertices you want in the object, select the vertex group you want in the Vertex Groups list, and press Assign

Comment: Thank you - I'll try it out.